# Should authenticate method return null or AuthentificationException?

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security

I have own spring srcurity auth provider:

```
public class MyLdapAuthProvider implements AuthenticationProvider

   @Override
   public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
          if(goodCredetials()){
             return authenticateUserPassword((UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) authentication);
           } else {
              throw new BadCredentialsException("bad credentials");
          }
    }
```

I don't understand what should I return if in method I understood that credentials is bad
1 - throw `AuthenticationException`
2 - return null

I have tested this and I don't see difference

### P.S.

spring securitu confguration:

```
<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider ref="provider1"/>
    <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="provider2"/>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

### P.S.

doc:

> Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)
>                                   throws AuthenticationException
>       Performs authentication with the same contract as AuthenticationManager.authenticate(Authentication).
>       Parameters:
>       authentication - the authentication request object.
>       Returns:
>       a fully authenticated object including credentials. May return null if the AuthenticationProvider is unable to support authentication
>   of the passed Authentication object. In such a case, the next
>   AuthenticationProvider that supports the presented Authentication
>   class will be tried.
>       Throws:
>       AuthenticationException - if authentication fails.

Comment: @brso05 will it lead to same result always?

Comment: @brso05 I believe that spring handles this exception

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.0.M1/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationProvider.html

Comment: But I don't understand difference

Answer (score 1):

Read the [doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationProvider.html) .  If you return null, you are telling spring that you can't support this Authentication method, and it should try the next provider (if any) in line.

My guess is that, if instead you throw, you break the chain of trying with different providers. It shouldn't make much difference as long as you have a single authProvider and not a collection of them.

Also, on failed auth, you should throw AuthenticationException, not BadCredentials?

Comment: I have 2 providers. I tried to throw exception in first, but second provider anyway successfully log in this user

Comment: *AuthenticationException* is abstract